# Como levantar servidor de cms?

Tags: api, servidor, hosting, vps, cms

Estoy intentado realizar una api con algún cms, intente primero con Strapi. Me funciona bien de manera local, pero no quisiera ser yo el que tenga que levantar  el servidor.
Alguien me puede explicar los pasos para que la api quede funcionando siempre como una api trandiconal?

Comment: Posiblemente tienes que configurar un servicio a nivel del sistema operativo para que, al momento de iniciarse, arranque el servicio que deseas.

Comment: Me refiero a no usar mi pc para levantarlo

Comment: Entonces tenes que instalar en algun hosting tu sistema... y eso, depende del hosting...

Comment: Genial, gracias por darme una idea! Lo agradezco